# Sinatra Returning empty parameters

Tags: ruby, parameters, get, sinatra, httprequest

I'm running a Sinatra application and whenever I send parameters to a post request everything works fine. However, if I'm sending the parameters to a get request, nothing is returned.

```
get "/test" do
  puts params
end
```

On my server, I'm returned `{}`. I have no idea what's going on. I'm running

```
gem "sinatra", "~> 1.4.3"
```

Using Mozilla's RESTClient, I plug in the correct url with the header name `content-type` and value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The body consists of

```
name=jason
```

Any help on what I'm missing here is much appreciated.

Comment: What parameters did you send with your get request?

Comment: `name=jason` using RESTClient.

Comment: Show your exact code for RestClient, so we can try to reproduce the problem. As is, you haven't satisfied Stack Overflow's requirements for a question. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
require 'restclient'

RestClient.get 'http://localhost:9393', 
               {:params => {:id => 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}}
```

.

```
require 'restclient'

RestClient.get 'http://localhost:9393', 
               :params => {:id => 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}
```

.

```
require 'restclient'

RestClient.get 'http://localhost:9393', 
               params: {id: 50, foo: 'bar'}
```

By the way, is it your belief that troubleshooting code is best accomplished when the code is invisible?  You didn't post your code initially, I asked for it, and you refused to give it.  What is your strategy with playing hide and seek?

> The body consists of...

GET requests do not have a body.

Comment: It's better to not even try to answer when the question is ambiguous or incomplete. You can waste time answering, then find out the OP had no idea what they were asking, or that the question was so badly written it was misunderstood. Don't put more work into the answer than the OP put into the question. Instead, you can downvote if you think the question deserves it, or vote to close it.

Comment: I wasn't playing hide and seek, I was sleeping. Also, I wasn't referring to rest client the gem, but rest client the add-on for Mozilla. For that part, I will take blame.

Comment: But get requests do allow parameters to pass through and for RESTClient, the only place that's possible is in the body portion of the app, unless I was to directly write the parameters into the url. Nevertheless, I think this goes beyond the scope of the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jason328, `But get requests do allow parameters to pass through and for RESTClient, the only place that's possible is in the body portion of the app, unless I was to directly write the parameters into the url.` Exactly.  If that add-on was programmed correctly, it would not show you a body input element when you chose GET.

Comment: @jason328, How do you specify a header?  Headers->Custom Header?  And why doesn't the add-on show you the actual request anywhere, e.g. next to the response so you can examine what the request actually looks like?

Comment: Yes, I'll specify a header via custom header. Once the request is sent from RESTClient to the server, generally RESTClient will then display all the details of the request. Unfortunately I'm at work and can't fiddle with it now, but I'll give an update later tonight when I can play with it some more.

Comment: @jason328, Okay thanks.  I can't get it to display the request information.

Comment: @jason328, Fyi, Here is a screenshot of exactly what I'm seeing: http://mozillamyanmar.org/2013/03/27/rest-client/